# Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone

Tags: iphone, coverflow

Are there any open source, CoverFlow-like APIs or libraries available for the iPhone?

I've found one implementation that is licensed per application, however, I'd much prefer to go the open source route.

Also, I'm interested in libraries that use only public APIs, as using non-public APIs might keep an app from getting published in the App Store.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The nice people at Chaosinmotion have got the following available:

http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html

It's BSD licensed.

Comment: The link generates a page load error...can you verify it's correct? Thanks

Comment: I've just re-checked it and it failed the first time I tried it and worked the second.  I'm not sure what's going on but it's shown at the top of a Google search for 'flowcover opengl es':

http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=flowcover+opengl+es&btnG=Search&meta=

You can use the cache to see it

Comment: Very cool, thanks for the link!

Comment: link is working right now... and it is good example for coverflow image view...

Comment: Warning: using this one would cause OpenGL texture blurring for you. Please consider OpenFlow below instead. If you are okay with blurring then use this one it has elegant animation.

Answer (score 42):

You might also want to check out a library I released at iPhoneDevCamp -- OpenFlow.
http://apparentlogic.com/openflow

It is all core animation-based, so it's easy to understand and customize to your needs. AFOpenFlowView is a subclass of UIView.

I included a demo application, and check out the blog entry on my personal website for a bit more information about its use. fajkowski.com

Drop me a line if you have any questions or comments!
-Alex

Comment: hi alex finding u frm long... you havent yet released the opensource which includes flip animation when the image is selected... Please look at it i am suffering from great prob due to it... Thanks in advance

Comment: hi alex . . i have a query . .is that possible to put up uiwebview instead of uimage and bring in the same reflections ? . if yes please get me few tips to accomplish this . thanks in advance

Comment: @thefaj how do i resize bigger images in coverflow??Could you please guide me in that direction?? or i have to put all images of same size??

Comment: Hi Alex... i want to refresh the cover flow... meaning add or remove images from cover flow on the fly. any suggestion, how can I do that?

Answer (score 35):

There's another nice Open Source implementation by demosthenese. Here's the [link](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel).

Comment: Out of all the links here, this is the most complete solution.

Comment: I agree this seems to be the best solutions, very simple to use, good example, many configuration options

Comment: Definitively worth taking a look, the best part is that you can use UIViews Directly rather than using UIImage.

Comment: That link no longer works. Is it the same one as https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: Thumbs up for this fabulous implementation!

Comment: It works  like a charm, really good examples, and high customization ! Thank you !!!

Comment: This looks like a really great solution

Answer (score 2):

The last chapter on Erica Sadun's [The iPhone Developer's Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321555457) is about Cover Flow.
You can grab the source code from the sample repository of the book on Google Code:
[cookbooksamples](http://code.google.com/p/cookbooksamples/downloads/list)

Comment: Unfortunately, Erica's solution uses aspects of the iPhone API that are not public.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any open-source libraries for what you describe above.  However, if you are familiar with core animation, it wouldn't be too hard to implement what you describe.

Check out the links below for some more information:

1. [Blog post about implementing coverflow using core animation](http://bruji.com/articles/tag/cover-flow/)
2. [Core animation reference guide from Apple iPhone Dec Center](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: > However, if you are familiar with core animation, it wouldn't be too hard to implement what you describe.
I'm not sure that it true. Coverflow is a reasonably complex animation.
Sadly, I don't think there are any public domain implementations.

Answer (score 0):

The book "SAMS Teach Yourself Cocoa Touch Programming in 24 Hours" shows you how to make your own in the CoreAnimation chapter (complete implementation).