# What does this error mean: "lo->hi recycling invariant violated!" and what can I do to fix it?

Tags: iphone, exc-bad-access, coverflow

My iPhone app started logging this error:
`lo->hi recycling invariant violated!`

followed by:
`Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”`

whenever I launched it on my iPod (3.1.3) and sometimes when I launch it in the simulator.

What does this error mean, and how can I fix it?

I am using cover-flow in my app.  I think this might be the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes cover flow is the problem. Note that `UICoverFlowLayer` is private API. If you're targeting for AppStore, [consider other alternatives here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library).

The error "lo->hi recycling invariant violated!" is raised by `-[UICoverFlowLayer _updateTick]`, which should be caused by reusing the wrong sublayer for display. The detail I don't know because there's no detail code, nor I'm familiar with the Cover Flow API.

Comment: It turns out, after some debugging, that the only thing wrong that the cover-flow was being initialized with zero covers.