# image Gallery in iPhone

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to Create an Image Gallery that may be use concept of scrolling and paging together.

When I click on a button, it will open a new view in landscape mode. This view is for my Image Gallery..

It shows 5 Images:

1. Centered Large Image With its description on Bottom.
2. Next Coming image on left side, This image is slightly tilled at some angle, Without any description at bottom.
3. next to next coming image on left to 2nd image.
4. previous  image on right side, This image is slightly tilled at some angle, Without any description at bottom.
5. Previous to Previous image on right of 4th image

Moreover, all images should be scrollable, like when I scroll 2nd image, it will move to Center and show its description and image which is already centered move to previous image.

Sorry for my confused English, here's an [example](http://docs.google.com/Doc?docid=0Aalr8n4hm7UaZGdreGQzOWZfMmd2aGJqdmd3&hl=en) of what I am trying to obtain. 
I tried for basic code of paging and scrolling but unluckily nothing helpful.

Could you give me some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Check out flowcover (see this question: [Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)), which should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I think someone reported flowcover doesn't work on iOS 4.0, I haven't tried yet, ofcourse. 
But, you can also take a look to this [OpenFlow](http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/) project, It will be help you I guess. Many people has builts their app on this library.