# iPad cover flow

Tags: iphone, ipad, coverflow

I use **FlowCoverView** (http://chaosinmotion.com/blog/?p=295) for cover flow.

However, the textures this library creates are limited to 256 pixels maximum, and I would like to show bigger images in an iPad cover flow.

What do you use for cover flow on the iPad? Is it possible to modify this library to make the textures bigger?

Comment: Probably it's just because the hardware is better. Any (freeware) example of those coverflow apps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source iPhone Coverflow like library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Comment: Edited question to differentiate it from other cover flow questions.

Comment: (just a thought) have you tried to define TEXTURESIZE to 512 instead of 256?

Comment: Is it only in the simulator that it doesn't work well, or have you tested it on the device too?  I know that I've seen significant improvement when running apps on an iPad device compared to the simulator, specifically when working with OpenGL stuff.

Comment: It's not a performance issue. FlowCoverView breaks if you change  TEXTURESIZE to something bigger to 256. The size of the "covers" is hardcoded it seems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just had a quick look at the code, without having ever used it or any other cover flow code before.

The FlowCoverView's imageToTexture method uses 256 in some places. It helps to replace them with TEXTURESIZE, too. With that, I can set TEXTURESIZE to 128 or 512 and it still works correctly with iPhone SDK 3.1.3 in the simulator, with the provided demo. That way, you can thus increase the texture size.

Does that help?

Comment: It requires more changes that that, but it's a step in the right direction.