# display images as displayed in iphone music album when seen in landscape mode?

Tags: iphone

i wanted to show my images in a similar way as we get to see different album names in our iphone player in landscape mode....is that possible??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source iPhone Coverflow like library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should help you out: http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/