# cover flow in iphone

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open source iPhone Coverflow like library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

hello all i want to develop cover flow application in my native iphone application please guide me how could i do that

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cover flow works by using the UICoverFlowLayer class, which is private and undocumented. If you attempt to use it, Apple will refuse to release your app on the app store.

You might be able to create a hand-made solution using Core Animation, but it would be difficult to accurately emulate the way cover flow works, and may also annoy Apple. Consider using some other interface.

[This discussion](http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10175986) on the Apple website has more information that you might find useful.

Answer (score 2):

See for instance [this](http://www.e-string.com/content/simple-example-afopenflow-open-source-cover-flow-alternative)

In principle you can use Opengl ES to create the animation having each 'cover' as a rendered UIIView (UIImage)