# how to add carousel effect in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, carousel

I want to add some carousel effect in my iphone application. i want to show some items in carousel effect. so can any one suggest how i do this ?

Thanks

Comment: You will need to be more specific...

Comment: I want to show aprox 10 or more images in the application. and for show these images i want to add the caroused effect in my application. for example see this effect :-
http://activeden.net/item/ultimate-3d-carousel-as2/full_screen_preview/49322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be answered here:
[Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

which links to a chaosinmotion open source file

This link is for flow cover(Carosel) Effect. This might be help you.
http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html

Assuming you mean a normal coverview view, I can't see your link due to company firewall issues!