# Use OpenFlow in iPad application

Tags: ipad, coverflow

OpenFlow is used in a lot iPhone apps, and there are several good posts about it

http://apparentlogic.com/openflow/

[Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

I also check out the source codes from github, but seems like it is one year ago.

Now, I plan to use it in iPad app. That means I need to know what need to change, and how to modify them.

So before action, post question here.

Thanks for your share.

********UPDATE****************

How about extending openflow with this way

Each image item is just button, like menus,double click on it will enter into new view, and in the new view there is "back" button to come back. Is that easy to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/09/how-to-add-coverflow-effect-on-your-iphone-app-openflow/