# flash iphone joomla/php

Tags: php, iphone, flash

i am using a flash slideshow everything is working fine but that slideshow is not working on Iphone/Ipad environment . please help

Comment: you may want to rephrase your question to avoid being downvoted into oblivion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using an UIScrollView.

Or Maybe you can use HTML5 with an UIWebView.

You can find some information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library).

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone/iPad doesn't support Flash

Comment: Yes i knew that , how can i implement a static image in place of flash in iphone/ipad

Comment: You should state that then, rather than expecting others to guess that you want a static image in place of the Flash. People cannot answer your question if you do not write your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

> how can i implement a static image in
>   place of flash in iphone/ipad? –
>   vipinsahu

Take a look at this article http://www.gskinner.com/blog/archives/2010/04/return_of_the_b.html. Grant Skinner has created a modified version of the SWFObject2.2 to display a lego brick icon when trying to view Flash content on an iDevice. You can modify the image of course.