# Are There Alternatives to the AFOpenFlow Framework?

Tags: iphone, coverflow

Has anyone ever worked with the AFOpenFlow Framework? Is there a better framework to implement an CoverFlow in my iPhone application?

Comment: I use it, it works nice and is very easy to use in an existing app.

Comment: Yes but this coverflow is in the centre of the iPhoen screen, do you know where i can implement it, that is in the top of the screen??? I hope you could help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-coverflow-library-for-iphone)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one also for an alternative....
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

or flowcover
http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html