# What is the iPhone API or Class that does picture scrolling with the cool reflection effect?

Tags: iphone

For example, in CNN's iPhone app, if you rotate the phone into landscape mode, it shows all the stories as pictures that you can scroll with your finger. It looks really polished with even a "reflection" effect. I've seen another app also do this, leading me to believe that it is a standard iPhone SDK API.
Here is a link to a screenshot from the CNN app so you can see what I'm talking about:

http://www.itnewsafrica.com/?p=8422

Anyone know what Class this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: [Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Also do a google search for Coverflow. I think that might do what you want or something close to it.