# Photo Slider Iphone

Tags: iphone, slider, photo, uislider

I  want to make a slider just like CNN's iphone application has.

http://i56.tinypic.com/15wdphg.jpg

i search all over but i didn't get any help even any clue. If some one has any idea than please share it with me, so i will make this slider.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open source iPhone Coverflow like library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That way of displaying images is called **Coverflow** - see the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library) discussing open-source libraries for iphone with cover-flow implementation.

To the libraries listed there I would also add [Tapku](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary) library.