# CoverFlow in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, coverflow

How to implement cover-flow in ipad..

is it possible is we can develop cover-flow in ipad ? , coz in ipad device it doesnt contain  cover-flow functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Maybe this could help

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but you'll have to build it yourself. Look into using Core Animation.