# Starbucks/IPod landscape like image browser for IPhone

Tags: iphone, image, user-interface

I am trying to figure out if there is a ready made view/viewcontroller similar to the Ipod landscape image browser (MPMediaPickerController seems to be portrait only).

It is also used by Starbucks app, when browsing drinks in landscape mode.

Regards,
Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at: [Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)