# iphone Carousel menu

Tags: iphone, animation

I like to develop an iphone app which contains Carousel style menu items. I found this style in "**CNBC RT iphone app**". I searched this over many times but there is no library available. Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean something like this:

[image]

Then your question has already been asked.  Check out this question on SO:

[Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Comment: Your name is awesome. Just sayin'.