# Circle view with scrolling?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am new to iPhone dev. Is it possible to create a not rectangle view. I need circle view with scrolling images in it. It will be the cards selector for my card game. Please give me advise How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several coverflow-like projects and libraries. Please check this thread: [Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-iphone-coverflow-like-library)

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure that it is all I need. I need it for my card game. It will be selector for my cards. I think that it will be done with help of Quartz or something else?

Comment: maybe this is helpful for you: https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.4088182973.04088182975.4092394252?i=2079986024 start with 424 and 425