# CoverFlow effect same with H&M app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, coverflow

Anyone know any sample code which make CoverFlow effect same with H&M app, please tell me, many thank. (H&M app [here](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/h-m/id380487409?mt=8))

Bellow is H&M app snapshot:

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this question, you might find what you're looking for : [Open source CoverFlow library for iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-coverflow-library-for-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

http://fajkowski.com/blog/2009/08/02/openflow-a-coverflow-api-replacement-for-the-iphone/

This worked for me. You might need to modify code if you want to run it to iPad.