# Display images in sequence in iPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to display a series of images like:
[image]

Can anyone please let me know, is there any API which by which I can display the images as shown in demo image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is known as coverflow in iOS. Follow [this link](http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html) you will get what you wanted and will come to know how to implement it.

Or you can [refer this question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-coverflow-library-for-iphone) too.

Comment: Thanks for your response. That's exactly I want.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some coverflow [controls in cocoa controlls](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=coverflow)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It's very useful for me.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use [Image Carousel](http://haifa.baluyos.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=60%3aobjective-c-image-carousel-tutorial&catid=1%3aprogramming&Itemid=5)

Tutorial there is pretty good, and really easy and quick to set up