# Source or APIs for this kind of view in iOS?

Tags: ios, scrollbar, scrollview

[image]

[image]

The screenshots are captured from an app called "Pulse".

I want to have this kind of view, something like a horizontal scrollview, and should have a delegate method to notify when the scroll stops.

Is there any sources or APIs for this kind of view?

Thanks

Comment: [Sounds like you are looking for an open source Coverflow view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-coverflow-library-for-iphone).

Comment: Try with [iCarousel](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel) I have used it in my projects and fits with your description

Comment: Coverflow is the keyword. Thanks. I didn't know what is it called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top component is coverflow and you can download sample code from below URL.

https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

bottom one is tableview. tableview is default component of iPhone SDK. you can use it with custom cell.