# Developing Notebook carousel in iOs app

Tags: ios, xcode, carousel

I want to create an iOS app to manage notebooks, i already know how to implement most of the functionality, but i would like to add a notebook carousel in the app like in the attached image. I have already googled for related terms searching for a way to do it with no avail.

It should animate on click and simulate the opening of a book, you can find this functionality in apps like penultimate, outliner and many others.

Can anyone put me in the right direction?

[image: notebook layout]

Comment: in case you dont want to develop everything from scratch ..u can use iCarousel. But please try to learn the Transformation related stuffs in it along with the velocity stuffs, very educative.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, i found this other opensource library http://www.chaosinmotion.com/flowcover.html which looks more like what i was looking for. got it from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718984/open-source-coverflow-library-for-iphone Much appreciated.